# Create groupings based on association

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table called 'activities'

```sql
activity_id
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

and a table called 'sequences'

```sql
activity_id associated_activity_id
----------- ----------------------
1           2 
1           3
2           4
5           6
6           7
```

I want to write a select query that will output this:

```
group_number activity_id
------------ -----------
1            1
1            2
1            3
1            4
2            5
2            6
2            7
```

Activities 1 - 4 are all in group 1 because they are all related in some way (i.e. activity 4 is in group 1 because it is related to activity 2, and activity 2 is related to activity 1). Activities 5 - 7 are in group 2 because they are all related but none of them are related to 1 - 4 (i.e. so they form a new group).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE for this purpose:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select row_number() over (order by activity_id) as group_id, activity_id
      from activity a
      where not exists (select 1 from sequences s where s.associated_activity_id = a.activity_id)
      union all
      select cte.group_id, s.associated_activity_id
      from cte join
           sequences s
           on s.activity_id = cte.activity_id
     )
select *
from cte
order by group_id, activity_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2670cf944a30c2155b8979b344a78ebb) is a db<>fiddle.